# RestKit Pagination mapping error

Tags: ios, pagination, restkit

The pagination documentation suggests:

The paginator must be configured with a pagination-mapping specifying how to configuration metadata is to be mapped out of the response payload. The configured mapping must have an objectClass of RKPaginator and should include attribute mappings for the currentPage, pageCount, perPage, and objectCount. For example, given a paginated resource loaded from ‘/articles?page=1’ with the following JSON:

```
 { "pagination": { "per_page": 10, "total_pages": 25, "total_objects": 250 }, "articles": [ // Array of articles ] }
```

But what if my API doesn't provide me with total_pages, but gives me total_objects? Obviously I can calculate my total pages from a combination of per_page and total_objects. I have a feeling this difference is causing my mappings not to map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be fine. The paginator actually uses `perPage` and `objectCount` to calculate the `pageCount` (the project is open source so you can verify this and debug what happens during the mapping).

If you turn on trace logging you should get good information about what's happening during the pagination mapping stage (like if it didn't map, it didn't have enough info or it did map and what the calculation was). Turn on trace logging with:

```
RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/ObjectMapping", RKLogLevelTrace);
RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network", RKLogLevelTrace);
```

Comment: holy crap - that log tracing is the business!!